# Can an iframe check if itself is in viewport or not?

Tags: javascript, iframe, viewport

I'm creating an `iframe` with a small HTML5 video. the video shouldn't start playing unless the `iframe` is in the viewport.

I noticed that this isn't as easy as I would like since the `iframe` is like a sandboxed environment. Is it even possible for an `iframe` to know if it is in the viewport?

Answer (score 1):

## Checking whether an element is in the viewport

[Here](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/check-if-an-element-is-visible-in-the-viewport/) you can find a nice implementation for checking whether an element is in the viewport:

```
function isInViewport(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}
```

## Reaching the parent window

Inside the `iframe` you can reach the parent `window` like this:

```
if (window.parent.isInViewport(document.querySelector('iframe'))) {
    //do something
}
```

(in the above I'm searching for the first `iframe` in the parent `window` for the sake of simplicity, you might need to change your selector)

Yet, modern browsers only allow this kind of communication if the page the `iframe` points to is of the same domain the main page points to. If the two pages are of different domains, then modern browsers will throw a [CORSS error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors).

You can have a [messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) between a main page and the page loaded into the `iframe` as an alternative, but for that purpose the developers of the main page need to cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

If the IFRAME source attribute "src" is executed in the same domain, you can do it but if the IFRAME take the src to a cross domain you need to be authorised to do it from the server where the file is hosted by configuring the CORS acceptation from your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntersectionObserver to monitor if the iframe enters viewport.
The code is pretty simple and clean if you go this way.

Here is a quick example of showing a youtube video on and off based on if the iframe is inside viewport.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          gap: 1rem;
          align-items: flex-start;
        }

        .box {
          background-color:lightblue;
          color: white;
          font-size: 4rem;
          text-align: center;
          margin: auto;
          height: 200px;
          width: 300px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-radius: 0.25rem;
          padding: 0.5rem;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">1</div>
        <div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
        <div class="box">4</div>
        <div class="box">5</div>

        <div class="box" id="divFrame">
            <iframe></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="box">6</div>
        <div class="box">7</div>
        <div class="box">8</div>
        <div class="box">9</div>
        <div class="box">10</div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        const iframeOserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            const iframe = entries[0].target.firstElementChild;
            iframe.src = entries[0].isIntersecting ? "https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1&mute=1": "";
            console.log("video " + (entries[0].isIntersecting ? "started" : "stopped"));
        }, { threshold: 0.5});

        iframeOserver.observe(document.getElementById("divFrame"));

    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I set the threshold of intersection to 50% (threshold: 0.5) in the above example. You can change it as you needed.

Please refer to the following link for details about IntersectionObserver:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API